# using of two different type of custom cell in same table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

thanks in advance. 
in my app, i have a tableview, in which i have to use two different style of custom cell, i made two custom cell, and in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method i used two identifier for cell, even i tried for two section. but its not working. it is giving me "EXE BAD Excess" or some time other kind of error. below is my code.

Error : thread1_EXE_BAD_Access(code = 2 ,address 0 x 0)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//CatIdentifier
static NSString *CellIdentiFier = @"CatIdentifier";
static NSString *Cell1IdentiFier = @"CatIdentifier1";

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
   CommitteCell *cell = ( CommitteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentiFier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {

       cell = ( CommitteCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommitteeCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    if (indicator == 1)
    {
      cell.lblName.text = str;

    }
    else
    {
      cell.lblName.text = [arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.lblPost.text = [arrayPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.picimg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

    }

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"link-bg 2.png"];

    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = img;


    return cell;
}


else 
{
    Committee2Cell *cell1 = (Committee2Cell  *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell1IdentiFier];
    if(cell1 == nil)
    {

        cell1 = (Committee2Cell  *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Committee2Cell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    cell1.lblPost1.text = strPost;
    cell1.txtName.text = strName;


    cell1.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"link-bg 2.png"];

    ((UIImageView *)cell1.backgroundView).image = img;

    return cell1;
 }

}
```

section in tableview and rows in section method are as below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 switch (section)
 {
    case 0:
        return [arrayName count]-1;
        break;
    case 1:
        return 1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }

  return 0;
 }
```

please if anyone can fine that where is my mistake . thanks again.

data of array and label is as below.

-(void)NewsParser:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic
   {
      NSLog(@"dic = %@",dic);

```
  arrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  arrayPost = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  arrayimage= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  strPost = [[NSString alloc]init];
  strName = [[NSString alloc]init];

  strPost = [[dic valueForKey:@"post"]objectAtIndex:8];
  strName = [[dic valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:8];

  NSLog(@"Name = %@",strName);
  NSLog(@"Post = %@",strPost);


  for(int i=0;i<[dic count]-1;i++)
  {
    [arrayName addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:i]];
    [arrayPost addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"post"]objectAtIndex:i]];
    [arrayimage addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"pic"]objectAtIndex:i]];
  }

  NSLog(@"array  = %@",arrayName);
  NSLog(@"array  = %@",arrayPost);
  NSLog(@"array  = %@",arrayimage);

  [table1 reloadData];


}
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Please provide your error codes. Double check that you import `ComitteeCell.h` and `Comittee2Cell.h` too

Comment: i imported both files.

Answer (score 0):

You R making reUsable identifier as only once . Do something like this :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView : (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       static NSString* identifier;
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
        identifier = @"0";
    else
        identifier = @"1";

   self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if( cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] ;

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{

    if(cell == nil)
    {

       cell = ( CommitteCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommitteeCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    if (indicator == 1)
    {
      cell.lblName.text = str;

    }
    else
    {
      cell.lblName.text = [arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.lblPost.text = [arrayPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.picimg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

    }

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"link-bg 2.png"];

    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = img;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it gives the same error. it display the section 0 , CommitteeCell custom cell and its data, and when i scroll down, it don't display section 1 and just show the Error : thread1_EXE_BAD_Access(code = 2 ,address 0 x 0)

Comment: I have edited back .. Check out and alter as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I think a cleaner approach would be to use a container view with two different kind of cells and then selectively show/hide the view relevant for that cell. This would be easier to code and maintain but might consume a little more memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suggested using `-objectForKey` for a Dictionary:

   `[[dic objectForKey:@"post"] objectAtIndex:8];`
2. Make sure there is a NSArray object at `name`/`post`/ `pic` keyed to `dic`
3. And, in your for loop:

   for(int i=0;i<**[dic count]**-1;i++) 
   {
           [arrayName addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"name"] **objectAtIndex: i**]];
           [arrayPost addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"post"]objectAtIndex:i]];
           [arrayimage addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"pic"]objectAtIndex:i]];
   }

are you sure `[dic count]` **<=** `[dic objectForKey:@"name"]`?
add a `nil` to array will be crashed.

4.Where did you call the method `-(void)NewsParser:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic;`, If your data array is correct, maybe the `[table1 reloadData];` crashed.

Comment: there is no problem in receiving data and that dic and at this array. view display section 0 table,which is arraypost nd array name and array image ,but when i scroll down, it dosn't display section 1's cell or data.

Comment: @zak it doesn't display section 1 OR it crashes? Check the Committee2Cell.xib, you can implement the `viewForHeaderInSection:1` to see if the section_1 displays.

Comment: it doesn't display section 1, it just display section 0 and when i scroll upto last row of section 0 , it will stop and shows the Error BAD Access.

Comment: I think your `Committee2Cell` has issues, in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` replace all `Committee2Cell` with `UITableViewCell`, comment `cell1.lblPost1.text = strPost;  cell1.txtName.text = strName;` , run with any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use like follow its work in my code smoothly , if you need more help let me know :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(YOUR CONDITION HERE)
       ShareActionViewCell *shareCell;
        NSString *ShareCellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ShareCell%d",indexPath.row];
        shareCell = (ShareActionViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ShareCellId];
        if(!shareCell) {
            shareCell = [[ShareActionViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ShareCellId];
        }
        shareCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        shareCell.ShareTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tbldata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    } else {

        CustCell *dataCell;
        NSString *DataCellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DataCell%d",indexPath.row];
        dataCell = (CustCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DataCellId];
        if(!dataCell) {
            dataCell = [[CustCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:DataCellId];
        }
        shareCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        shareCell.ShareTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tbldata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
}
```